# AngularJS [$compile:nodomevents]

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

### Why “this” around an angularjs item does not work?

I have a table like this

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="brand in brands">
   <td>{{brand.name}}</td>
   <td>
     <input id="orderInput" onkeyup="setOrder({{brand.id}}, this.value);" 
       type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" value=" 
       {{brand.order}}" placeholder="Sort Order" />
   </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and this method

```
<script>
    function setOrder(brandId, order) {
        $.ajax('/admin/SetOrderBrand?brandId=' + brandId + '&order=' + 
        order);
    }
</script>
```

but I get this error

> angular.min.js:127 Error: [$compile:nodomevents]http://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.5/$compile/nodomevents
>
> ```
>  at angular.min.js:7
>  at Ia (angular.min.js:87)
>  at rc (angular.min.js:68)
>  at Xa (angular.min.js:65)
>  at Xa (angular.min.js:65)
>  at Xa (angular.min.js:65)
>  at fa (angular.min.js:63)
>  at angular.min.js:69
>  at d (angular.min.js:66)
>  at m (angular.min.js:70)
> ```

For example, If I change my input like this, page will work correctly.

```
 <input id="orderInput" onkeyup="setOrder(1, this.value);" 
       type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" value=" 
       {{brand.order}}" placeholder="Sort Order" />
```

but I need brand's id in each row, so the first property in method must be dynamic.

How to fix it?

Comment: Are you certain that `{{brand.id}}` is outputting an integer value? If it's a string then you'll need to wrap it with quotes.

Comment: Remove `{{brand.id}}` and try using `brand.id` only

Comment: if you want to use jquery event in angular then you should create directive

Comment: Use `ng-keyup `

Comment: @MayankVadiya, Can you explan more?

Comment: @SudhirOjha, it doesn't work

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, yes i'm sure it's integer.

Comment: @FarshadShahsavari You should define the function in the controller. Create a controller and then add this setOrder function inside of that controller.

Comment: Use `ng-keyup="setOrder(brand.id, brand.order);` like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs when one tries to create a binding for event handler attributes or properties like `onclick`, `onload`, `onsubmit`, etc.

There is no practical value in binding to these attributes/properties and doing so only exposes your application to security vulnerabilities like XSS. For these reasons binding to event handler attributes and properties (`formaction` and all starting with `on`) is not supported.

For more information, see [AngularJS Error Reference - $compile:nodomevents](https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.5/docs/error/$compile/nodomevents)

Comment: Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Instead of `onkeyup` use the `ng-keyup` directive. Create a controller and then add the `setOrder` function inside of that controller. Use the `ng-model` directive to acquire the value of the input. Instead of using jQuery `.ajax`, use the AngularJS `$http` service.